# Can I do full text searches with jquery Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to be able to search a list of full names. The autocomplete demos I have seen have all searched from the beginning. Thats no good as I want matches on surname too.

I can live without full text search if it at least follows word boundaries. Sorta like the tag search here. Hows that done?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can. Just take the items from a server side function that does the actual search. For example a SQL server. You should consider performance. High number of row may take long enough to have a "flaky" autocomplete.

Comment: I only have like 300 items. Ajax seems kinda like over kill.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that searches both first and last names even when you have multiple partial words in your search term:

```js
var arrayOfNames = [{first:"John", last:"Box"},{first:"Rachel", last:"Park"}
               ,{first:"Rachel", last:"Dark"},{first:"Rachel", last:"Luck"}];

$("#input").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var names = [];
        var searchTerms = request.term.split(" ");;
        $.grep(arrayOfNames, function(person, i) {
            var matches = 0;

            $.each(searchTerms, function(i, term) {
                if(person.first.indexOf(term)>=0 || person.last.indexOf(term)>=0)
                    matches++;
            });

            if(matches == searchTerms.length)
                names.push({value:person.first+" "+person.last});
        });

        response(names);
    }
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/t29req1s/1/